# JBMRS: Creating Facts

Tags: java, jboss, drools, fact

Which one will be better for a project using JBRMS, JBPM inside an ESB: Creating fact types inside the BRMS or uploading POJO's? As per my understanding, creating fact types inside BRMS have advantage like, if there is anything to be added later on we can make a simple change inside and write a rule. Which will be a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

POJOs are usually better as you have more tooling (IDE's) to deal with them, you can use the same POJOs in your application code without recurring to specific API (drools API or java reflection), it is easier to reuse the facts among multiple DRLs, among a few other advantages.

The main use case for the declarative model is to define fact types that are only used inside the rules (not referenced by the application).